# как создать в outlook карпаративные подписи используя exchange 2019 или GPO в AD

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, outlook, exchange

Установлен exchange 2019
Настроены подписи, сообщение заявление об отказе, сделаны исключения в правилах через метки в теме “RE:” (чтоб портянка дублей подписи не копилось в конце)
Все бы хорошо, но пользователям необходимо видеть эти подписи в открытом письме, как это устроить?

1. Как-то выдернуть подпись из exchange2019 и вставить в шаблон Outlook в путь (C:\Users\пользователь\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures)
2. По пути создать шаблон C:\Users\ пользователь \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures и выдернуть переменные из AD но у меня этот способ не получился
3. Написать VBS (или powershell) скрипт, я не силен в написании скриптов, пробовал разные, но результата не дало
   Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как выйти из ситуации?

Comment: Ну а что ты нагуглил в для связки почтовика и пошика? Я имею ввиду какие коммандлеты ты начал запускать и у тебя стало выдавать ошибку?